# Mac OS Mojave: "brew install --HEAD valgrind" fails. Suggested online solutions do not work

Tags: macos, homebrew, memory-leaks, macos-mojave, valgrind

When attempting

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

I get this error:

> ==> Deleted Formulae apache-arrow        cputhrottle         liblastfm           ruby@1.8 apache-arrow-glib   hyper               percona-server@5.6
>
> valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected
>   on macOS versions newer than High Sierra due to an upstream
>   incompatibility. Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
>   Moes-MacBook-Pro:~ moesanjaq$ brew install --HEAD valgrind
>   ==> Cloning https://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git Updating /Users/moesanjaq/Library/Caches/Homebrew/valgrind--git fatal: dumb
>   http transport does not support shallow capabilities Error: An
>   exception occurred within a child process:   DownloadError: Failed to
>   download resource "valgrind" Failure while executing; `git fetch
>   origin --unshallow` exited with 128. Here's the output: fatal: dumb
>   http transport does not support shallow capabilities

When attempting

```
brew install valgrind
```

I get a much shorter error message

> valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected
>   on macOS versions newer than High Sierra due to an upstream
>   incompatibility. Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

I attempted following this article:
https://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2018/04/28/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-high-sierra/

After making the changes the head section of

```
 brew edit valgrind
```

looks like

> head do
>
> ```
> url "git://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git"
>
> depends_on "autoconf" => :build
>
> depends_on "automake" => :build
>
> depends_on "libtool" => :build
> ```
>
> end

Now when attempting

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

I get to the build step and then this error:

> => Checking out branch master Already on 'master' Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'. HEAD is now at e911f75 Fix
>   callgrind_annotate Use of uninitialized value in numeric gt (>)
>   ==> ./autogen.sh
>   ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-e911f75 --enable-only64 Last 15 lines from /Users/moesanjaq/Library/Logs/Homebrew/valgrind/02.configure: checking
>   for gcc-ar... no checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl checking for
>   gdb... /no/gdb/was/found/at/configure/time checking dependency style
>   of clang... none checking for diff -u... yes checking for clang option
>   to accept ISO C99... none needed checking for a supported version of
>   gcc... ok (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0) checking build system type...
>   x86_64-pc-darwin checking host system type... x86_64-pc-darwin
>   checking for a supported CPU... ok (x86_64) checking for a 64-bit only
>   build... yes checking for a 32-bit only build... no checking for a
>   supported OS... ok (darwin) checking for the kernel version...
>   unsupported (18.2.0) configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 10.x,
>   11.x, 12.x, 13.x, 14.x, 15.x, 16.x and 17.x (Mac OS X 10.6/7/8/9/10/11 and macOS 10.12/13)
>
> READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting

When attempting

```
brew install valgrind
```

I get the same error as previous:

> valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected
>   on macOS versions newer than High Sierra due to an upstream
>   incompatibility. Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Am I doomed to find my leaks manually when developing on Mac OS Mojave?

Comment: Valgrind says they have some upstream issue they can't fix right now

Comment: maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714807/unable-to-build-and-install-valgrind-on-macos-high-sierra) can give you some clue how to resolve this.